# Не работает media screen при просмотре с мобильных устройств

Tags: css

Имеется такой код:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 765px){
.menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

когда я изменяю размер браузера код работает, но при просмотре с телефона или эмулятора телефона элементы не исчезают. Что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: на codepen.io и с телефона работает и с эмулятора (google chrome f12 -> ctrl+shift+m), а вот с рабочего стола запускаю страницу в эмуляторе не работает (css файл подключен)

Comment: да, есть, могу скинуть, реально не робит

Comment: спасибо большое, <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> вот этого не хватало)